# SQL Join Query Select

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following Tables  :

**Table : product**

```
--------------------------       
id_product |  name_product                               
--------------------------      
1          | p1                            
2          | p2                
3          | p3
```

**Table : number**

```
-----------------------
 imei      | id_product  
-----------------------
 56789     | 1   
 56799     | 2
 56713     | 3
```

**Table : Operatio**

```
----------------------
imei     |  date
------------------
56789    |31-07-2017
```

At last I want to get this result :

```
---------------------------------------
 name_product | number_operation  
---------------------------------------
 p1           | 1   
 p2           | 0
 p3           | 0
```

Thanks You

Comment: You can complete this task with a few inner joins. Start by working from a `SELECT * FROM product`. Then inner join it with number based on the 2 id_product columns. At last you're gonna do an inner join again based on the imei's in number & Operatio. I'm not sure what you want with the output `number_operation`, but if it's the index of the operation, then i'm sorry. But can't help you with that. I'm a postgres user and I don't think SQL has an order to elements in the database.

Comment: what output you want? state it clearly

Comment: @johnHc i want to count how many products in operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count the number of operations by product:

```
select name_product, sum(num_op)
from product p1
left join number n2
  on n2.id_product = p1.id_product
left join
    (
    select imei, count(operation) as num_op
    from Operation
    group by imei
    ) x
  on x.imei = n2.imei
group by name_product
```

For the number of products that have had an operation:

```
select name_product, count(distinct o3.imei)
from product p1
left join number n2
  on n2.id_product = p1.id_product
left join Operation o3
  on o3.imei = n2.imei
group by name_product
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution :

```
SELECT name_product, COUNT(*)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN number n ON n.id_product = p.id_product
LEFT JOIN operation o ON o.imei = n.imei
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product.id_product,COUNT(number.id_product)
FROM product
INNER JOIN number ON product.id_product = number.id_product;
GROUP BY product.id_product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   name_product, count (imei) c
FROM   (SELECT   name_product, o.imei
          FROM      (SELECT   p.name_product, n.imei
                       FROM   product p, "number" n
                      WHERE   p.id_product = n.id_product) t
                 LEFT JOIN
                    Operatio o
                 ON t.imei = o.imei)
GROUP BY   name_product
```

Try this code